# SQL query, linking one table back to itself

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to link a table back to itself, for example, I have a videos table and I would like suggested videos link back to the videos table but the values are displayed as blank. Any help?

```
create table video_suggestions (
video_id int,
suggestion_id int );

insert into video_suggestions(video_id,suggestion_id)
values (20,32),(29,9),(12,38),(4,50),(6,14),(1,18),(35,40),(15,48);

Create table suggested_videos (
video_id int,
suggestion_id int );

insert into suggested_videos(suggestion_id,video_id)
values (32,20),(9,29),(38,12),(50,4),(14,6),(18,1),(40,35),(48,15);

select videos.title as current_video,videos.title as suggested_video
from videos,suggested_videos,video_suggestions
where videos.video_id=video_suggestions.video_id
and suggested_videos.suggestion_id=videos.video_id;
```

Comment: What does your `Videos` table look like ? Also you have selected the same column twice in your select statement `videos.title` with two different Aliases `current_video` and `suggested_video`

Comment: It has video_id and title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT V1.[title] AS current_video
      ,V2.[title] AS suggested_video
FROM      video_suggestions VS 
LEFT JOIN suggested_videos SV  ON VS.suggestion_id = SV.suggestion_id
LEFT JOIN videos V1    ON   VS.video_id = V1.video_id
LEFT JOIN videos V2    ON   SV.video_id = V2.video_id
```

Comment: When I use this code, it gives me triple values and it is the same title and its not different.